# WebApi complex object returned as null

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a ASPNET WebApi 2 project and in a controller i have two actions

```
 public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri] Company company)
 {
    //code
 }
```

and the other:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/company/quantity")]
public IHttpActionResult Count([FromUri] Company company)
{
      //code
}
```

the Company class:

```
  public class Company 
  {
    public Company()
    { 
       Name = "";
       //Set default value to all properties
    }
    public string Name {get;set;}
    //othger string properties
  }
```

If i access the first method **Get** with this uri : ***//localhost/api/company/*** everything goes ok, and the `Company` object comes instantiate with default values.

But if i try to access the second method Count with this uri : ***//localhost/api/company/quantity*** the method is hit but the `Company` object is null.

Whats wrong?

Comment: Add DataContract and DataMember attributes to the Company class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the route attribute for your second method and put company into brackets.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/{company}/quantity")]
public IHttpActionResult Count([FromUri] Company company)
{
    //code
}
```

However, are you trying to pass a complex object via URL? you could better switch to a POST/PUT method and bind object from request body.

Comment: Yes, but its not my own project, just working on it, ill try to change it later.

Comment: The company is the name of the controller too. And the problem is that in the first method (Get(Company company)) the company constructor is hit before the action, so it comes with default values. But in the second method (Count(Company company)) the Company constructor isnt hit, so the object comes null. In both cases i dont pass anything in the url.

Comment: We should not use POST simply because we are trying to "pass a complex object". REST semantics should be respected: if we are trying to GET something, we should not use POST to obtain it. POST implies changing state, GET implies retrieving information.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass a complex object like class using httpget the way to send is to change the verb to either post or put and send the object one the body of the http request

Comment: Yes, but why in the first method it works? Its get verb too.